# Kubuntu 20.04 - sometimes frame rate decreases

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, display

I just installed Kubuntu 20.04 with a proprietary Nvidia 440 driver.
It's working fine, but sometimes for some reason I see, that frame rate suddenly drops; Compositing and window moving is not smooth, as it was after OS startup.

I din't open new apps when this occurs; it just strikes randomly. I have dual monitors set up. If I change anything in monitor settings (like the position of monitors) and click apply, then it works smoothly again (after the screens blink).

How can I find out what causes this behavior?

```
vvyshko@kb:~/Projects/k8s/scaling-nwsd-chat$ sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)
    product: System Product Name (SKU)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 137
        Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: What's your display adapter? Please run _sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)_  then highlight the text, do Ctrl-Shift-C to copy the text, switch back to here, click [edit],, and paste that info back into your question.

Comment: Thanks @K7AAY, thanks, I added this info to my question. I also added an answer which is worked for me, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the original issue, but I solved it by the following steps:

1. Disabled all KDE/Kwin vsync options.
2. Generated nvidia-config `xrorg.conf` for both monitors
3. Added `{ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}` Xorg option for both monitors, so my screen section looks like

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-4"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-2: 1920x1200 +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}, DP-4: 2560x1440 +1920+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

It started to work even better then it was before the refresh rate down.
Hope this will help to somebody or for me in the future :)

Would be nice to find out the original problem with Kwin (?)